# Childrens Album with raindrops and instruments

Tags: music

Growing up my church nursery had 2 records we always listened to...one i was able to find (it was from the Aunt Bea series), and the other one I only remember vaguely, but it was about raindrops and instrument sounds. I'm not sure it was a Christian album. Probably from the 70s or 80s. I k it its a long shot but maybe someone remembers! Thanks!

Comment: Do you still know anyone that was part of the congregation at the time? Even better, do you still know anyone that would have been in the nursery with you? You could try asking them if they at least can add detail to your recollection.